# a "migrated" message and basically a surprise transfer to new site upon selection.

Tags: feature-request, migrated

As I go through the messages in a given stackexchange, I notice messages that are marked as "migrated". The migrated site is not identified.  And sure enough you select a migrated, you are thrown to the new stackexchange site to see the message.

The current operation is a tad confusing to me.

I would like to suggest a reference link at the "transferred from" stackexchange website so the the user could decide to go to the transferred link.  Thus "transferred from" website could contain the title, and question and the link for the responses (or to submit a response).

Something like this would confuse me less.

Comment: The auto-redirection is a pain in the tender spots and disorienting. Seems like creeping featurism. (Either that or I'm just generally bitter and angry)

Comment: Thanks for a minute there I thought I was the only one that had a problem with the auto-direction feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *used* to be the behaviour of the migrated questions on the stack exchange sites. However, there was nothing for you to do on a migrated question except view the question. All the answers were made invisible so that they couldn't be edited or even relied upon, as the migrated question may have much more up to date answers and we really don't want to spread old or incorrect information on the web.

You can see for yourself by putting a `?noredirect=1` on the end of the URL to a migrated question (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751219/apache-mina-ftpserver-issue-authentication-failed-but-used-correct-user-pass?noredirect=1))

You'll see that viewing the question on the original site isn't of any use because there's nothing you can do with it, hence why the question now takes you directly to the migrated-to site.

Comment: ahh....can the "migrated" message on the "list" page indicate the place the message got migrated to?  Instead of just "migrated"?

Comment: BTW, I must have been used to the previous behavior and thought it was ok.  Just still surprised as to how it now works. :-)

Comment: @mdpc - If you want to propose that suggestion, the best place to do it would be on http://meta.stackoverflow.com as there it will be seen by the wider community and, most importantly, the devs :)

Comment: Gee....why not migrate this message to meta.stackoverflow.com! :-)

Comment: Mark Henderson: thanks for the tip I did ask the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99380/can-the-migrated-message-on-the-list-page-indicate-the-place-the-message-got

Comment: @mdpc - I can't migrate from here to mso unfortunately :)

Comment: Mark Henderson:  Is this due to an incorporated design feature or a lack of priv in the other StackExchange site?  Just curious.

Comment: @mdpc, it's by design.

Comment: @mdpc - it's because there are dozens of migration paths for every site, so they can't account for all of them. MSO itself has *no* migration paths out of it ;)

Answer (score 7):

We already do have pointers going both directions.

On the ServerFault side:

[image: ServerFault migrated question]

And on the destination site:

[image: WebMasters migrated question]

As Mark pointed out, it used to be the case that you'd get the SF page first with a link to the migrated question. You'd have to click on the link to see how it was fareing on the target. Now it just redirects you. To see the SF side, click on that link I pointed to.

Comment: I actually prefer the auto-follow behavior.  I think it is more intuitive, given the change in the migrated question's title on the source site and all...

Comment: I also think it's more friendly. Auto-follow says the user: "OK, your question wasn't a good fit here, but we aren't mad at you and sent it over to our friends at SO/SU", and when he clicks on it, he get an active question window at the correct site. Without this behaviour, he is seeing a closed question and must first search and find the info on how to proceed. I am sure, many users didn't really understood that and left frustrated.